# Conditional statement only reacts to initial values of slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, uislider, conditional-statements

I have a slider (with range) on my page and I want an image to appear or disappear depending on the range set   by the user. I do this with a conditional statement at the end of my code. The conditional statement reacts correctly to the initial values [1500,1600] of the slider but it does not react to users moving the slider, hence changing the values.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 300,
        max: 3000,
        values: [ 1500, 1600 ],
        step: 10,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val(
        "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )
    );

    var handlevalues = ( $("#slider-range").slider('values') );

    var dot0001 = { price: 1300 }


    if (handlevalues[0] > dot0001.price) {
        $("#dot0001").css("visibility", "hidden")
    } else {
        $("#dot0001").css("visibility", "visible")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the same conditional statement to your `slide` function:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );

    var dot0001 = { price: 1300 };
    if (handlevalues[0]>dot0001.price){
        $("#dot0001").css("visibility", "hidden");
    } else{
        $("#dot0001").css("visibility", "visible");
    }

}
```

To avoid repeating code, you could put that statement in a separate function, and call it from both places.

Comment: It works but I have another question... there are a lot of images and they all have the same id structure ("dot****"). Same applies to all the objects ( var=dot****). Do you know how I can automate the whole thing? Can you post it as another answer? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Maybe you should post it as a separate question, with further details?